# Is there any way to programmatically handle S3 RequestTimeTooSkewed error without changing the local clock

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have read all about this issue online. I understand the check is done by Amazon and I cannot control it.

The problem is that my program can be installed on hundreds of desktops. I will not have the ability to fix the clocks for all these desktops.

I can get the correct time from a server call and calculate the time skew. Is there anyway to pass the fixed time to Amazon via the AWS .NET SDK so that the time skew error goes away?

I already tried passing the request headers - it does not work.

```
putRequest.Headers["Date"] = time;
putRequest.Headers["x-amz-date"] = time;
```

Comment: x-amz-date works around that, but you need to make sure that "time" is not too skewed.

Answer (score 1):

After extensive research I found the answer. There is a bug in the latest AWS SDK which will not let the dates you specify actually go across to S3. So the current API:

1. Ignores the time values passed via the headers from the API. In any case, the `x-amz-date` is definitely overridden.
2. Builds the signature for the authorizer using the default time from the skewed local clock.

To work around the issue, download [the latest AWS SDK source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net) from Amazon. I did the following to ensure both date and `x-amz-date` are the same, and take the values passed to the API:

*aws-sdk-net-master\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:*

```
public override void InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
```

- If the `x-amz-date` and date is present within `wrappedRequest.Headers`, and they are not equal, set the `x-amz-date` from the date.

*aws-sdk-net-master\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Auth\AWS3Signer.cs:*

```
private static void SignHttp(IRequest request, RequestMetrics metrics, string awsAccessKeyId, string awsSecretAccessKey)
private static void SignHttps(IRequest request, ClientConfig clientConfig, RequestMetrics metrics, string awsAccessKeyId, string awsSecretAccessKey)
```

- If the `request.Headers` contains the `x-amz-date` header, set the "date" local variable to it, otherwise set it to the value passed in the date header.

*aws-sdk-net-master\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Auth\S3Signer.cs:*

```
internal void SignRequest(IRequest request, RequestMetrics metrics, string awsAccessKeyId, string awsSecretAccessKey)
```

- If the `request.Headers` does not contain the `x-amz-date` header and it does contain the date header, set the value from the date header, otherwise just let it do what it currently does.

*aws-sdk-net-master\AWSSDK_DotNet35\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Auth\CloudFrontSigner.cs:*

```
public override void Sign(IRequest request, ClientConfig clientConfig, RequestMetrics metrics, string awsAccessKeyId, string awsSecretAccessKey)
```

- If the `request.Headers` contains the `x-amz-date` header, set the "dateTime" local variable to it, otherwise set it to the value passed in the date header.

IMPORTANT:

After you compile with these code changes, pass the time to the request from the API call using:

```
//DATE TIME HAS TO BE IN THIS FORMAT
string time = AWSSDKUtils.GetFormattedTimestampRFC822(<time skew in minutes>); 
request.Headers[HeaderKeys.DateHeader] = time;
request.Headers[HeaderKeys.XAmzDateHeader] = time;
```

The time skew can be found out by getting the date from any server and subtracting the local time. Note however that time skew changes especially on VMs and sometimes it gets worse, sometimes it gets corrected by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can send request of completion handler and response it can set your skew time then you can resend your request.
if your time is more than 5 6 months amazon server will not allowed us to do anything so it don't help when time is more than 5 6 month

```
//403 code have clockskew error but 403 also used for some other kind errors
//if error is not skewerror than nothing going to disturb over method**

++ (void)updateTimeSkew:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request withReponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{

    if (response.httpStatusCode == 403)
    {
        //Getting DateTime from Request
        NSString * requestDateTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request.urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields[@"Date"]];

        //Converting Datestring into Date Format
        NSDateFormatter * requestDateFormat= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        requestDateFormat.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
        requestDateFormat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

        //Assigning date from dateFormatter
        NSDate *requestDate =[requestDateFormat dateFromString:requestDateTimeString];

        //Converting Datestring into Date Format
        NSDateFormatter *serverTimeformat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        serverTimeformat.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
        serverTimeformat.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

        //Getting Date from amazon response
        NSString *responseDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",response.responseHeader[@"Date"]];
        NSDate *serverTime = [requestDateFormat dateFromString:responseDate];

        //Calculating Time differnce
        NSTimeInterval time =  [requestDate timeIntervalSinceDate:serverTime];

        //Setting clockSkew
        [AmazonSDKUtil setRuntimeClockSkew:time];
    }
}
```